# failed to create more than one thread with #pragma omp parallel for

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, openmp

all.
I am a beginer of OpenMP. 
I want to use OpenMP like this:

```
float* Arrays;
int OneArrayLength = 100;
float* ArrayPointers[ArrayNums];
for(int i = 0; i < ArrayNums; i ++)
{
    ArrayPointers[i] = Arrays + i*OneArrayLength;
}
#pragma omp parallel for
for i = 0 to LastPointer
{
    Algorithm al;
    al.process(ArrayPointers[i])
}
```

And it did not work as i expect. 
I can compile the codes and run it, but it did not get faster.

Update: Thanks to @nogard. Setting project setting to support (openmp) realy worked.
There is another reason that i failed to solve this problem. I use Interl diagnostic tool to get the .gap file. And it gave nothing about optimization of this loop, while it could gave some suggestions about how to optimize other loops.
I am confused about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't put the appropriate project setting:

```
Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support -> Yes (/openmp)
```

By default this flag is not set, so OpenMP is simply disabled

To test the number of OpenMP threads you can run this simple program:

```
int iam = 0;
int np = 1;

#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(iam, np)
{
  #if defined (_OPENMP)
    np = omp_get_num_threads();
    iam = omp_get_thread_num();
  #endif
  std::cout << "Hello from thread " << iam << " out of " << np << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: yes. you are right! I write these codes in one project which export a dll and the executing project, which import the dll, is another project. So I forgot to put the excuting project setting.

Comment: Hi, nogard. Thank you very much for your answer. I add a reason that i failed to get this problem. Would you please answer it?